# Swap z and y keys on Xperia Mini Pro with Android 4.0

Tags: keyboard

I got a Xperia Mini Pro with a hardware keyboard, which has a German layout. I switched to US layout on the computer and would like to use that on the phone as well.

Is there some way to change the layout of the phone? I do not care about the button labels.

## Update

I checked the “Language and Input” section of the settings:

http://wstaw.org/m/2013/04/27/Screenshot_2013-04-27-21-48-01.png

For German (“Deutsch”), I can only select QWERTZ and AZERTY, but not the QUERTY that I want.

http://wstaw.org/m/2013/04/27/Screenshot_2013-04-27-21-48-13.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Sony devices might have a different keyboard pre-installed. But the usual place to look for this is *Settings→Language & Input*, look for *Keyboards and input methods*. Here you should be able to configure your keyboard:

On my ICS device, next to each input method available is a "gear symbol". Tapping that, opens the settings for that input method. The topmost entry is labeled something with "Input Language". Tap that, and you'll find the available languages, again with a "gear symbol" letting you select the keyboard layout.

As all languages in the list have their keyboard layouts announced, you might also simply enable the language with the correct layout there. My list e.g. has:

- English (QWERTY)
- English (AZERTY)
- English (QWERTZ)

So you'ld just need to enable the one you want. You also can enable multiple languages you then can switch between directly from the keyboard, of course.

Comment: I can select the languages, I can select English, but there are no options for changing the layout to anything but QWERTY and AZERTY.

Comment: In that case I have to pass out. Maybe one of the alternative keyboards available on the playstore might offer a solution -- or somebody else knows a "trick"...

Comment: Will that work for a hardware keyboard?

Comment: For a hardware keyboard, there was even an app to configure it. If it's about that, take a look at [External Keyboard Helper Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo) and, if the features are convincing and your device compatible, you might need to "go pro" -- but all I've heard that should be amazing!